# Ignore a specific package while installing dependencies using 'npm install'

Tags: node.js, git, react-native, github, npm

I have a node package `react-native-push-notification` for which i have made some changes in the packages to fulfil my requirement. But every time i do a `npm install` the new (original package without my changes) package overlaps with my current package.

Is there any way i can restrict `npm install` to ignore my modified package? And also i want to push this package to git.

Any lead will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have made some changes to the already existing node package `react-native-push-notification` and you would rather use your own version of it than the original.

You have a couple of options:

- In `package.json` change `react-native-push-notification` to point to your git repo (e.g. your fork on github). This is not ideal since it makes semver problematic. But it works.
- Rename your fork of the package and use that directly from npm. E.g. rename to `react-native-push-notification2` or even better, use a scoped package name e.g. `@yournick/react-native-push-notification` and publish that to npm. Change your `package.json` to use this package instead.
- Convince the authors of the original package to incorporate your changes. This is the ideal solution, but might be difficult to get your patch merged etc.

Comment: Hi, Forking the repo help me with the solution but is it legal to publish the code into npm with my account?

Comment: @HungrySoul. you can't publish into someone's npm account. you can only publish to your own and there cannot be two package of same name. so you have to give it a new name and use it

Comment: @HungrySoul. you can't publish into someone npm account. you can only publish to your own and there cannot be two package of same name. so you have to give it a new name and use it

Comment: @HungrySoul No you can't publish to the same package name obviously, since you don't have access to that. Hence, why you need to _change_ the package name to something that's available that you _can_ publish to.

Answer (score 2):

`patch-package` is exactly what you're looking for: https://github.com/ds300/patch-package

It will preserve your changes even after running `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this would be to fork the repo https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/.

This way, you have control of the contents of the package.

Then update your `package.json` with your repo address.

I also would recommend not pushing your packages to Git. Packages are already under version control (in their own repo) and pushing to Git just bloats your repo for no reason.

Comment: Thank you it worked. But I have one query? Is it legal?

Comment: Fwiw, this isn't the ideal solution since it messes up semver.

Comment: If you are forking a open repo then yes. As long as you adhere to the terms and conditions of the package - https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/master/LICENSE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it very easily. Fist of all go to the plugin GitHub repository then fork it to your profile. Before if you want to install this plugin from the direct repo, you have to run this command -

```
npm i https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification.git
```

But after successful fork, it will install the modified files that you have made changes and the command should be -

```
npm i https://github.com/YourUserName/react-native-push-notification.git
```

and boom your modified files never will change.