# Skip install for particular dep

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-registry

Is there a way to run `npm install` but skip a particular dependency?

Something like:

```
npm install --skip=lodash --skip=rxjs
```

In my case, I have some developer tooling and some dependencies may not actually be in the NPM registry yet, so I want to skip those.

I am looking to skip installation of a particular dependency, and put a dummy package in its place.

Assuming this feature does not exist yet, I filed a related feature request on the NPM community forum:
https://npm.community/t/allow-npm-install-to-work-with-missing-dependencies/1526

Comment: Seet his: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999921/ignore-a-specific-package-while-installing-dependencies-using-npm-install

Comment: Why not just use peer dependencies?

Comment: This is for a library, I don't have control over which deps go where.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using "**--no-optional**" argument which will prevent optional dependencies from being installed.

Comment: that will skip the deps in the optional set, but not an arbitrary dependency, I am looking to skip installation of a particular dependency, and put a dummy package in its place.

Comment: This might help for some, but not for us: In our setup, external developers don't have a particular dependency and they do not need it. We can declare it as optional and they can use "no-optional", but that  does not help, when they perform "npm install ..." to install a new package, then the resulting package-lock.json is incorrect. We then need to merge the file manually when we take over their work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)? If you have local customized versions of a package, such as say `/home/me/hacked-npm/lodash`, you can simply

1. Run `npm link` from `/home/me/hacked-npm/lodash`
2. `cd` to the project where you want to use the modified dependency
3. Do your `npm install` and pull down everything like normal
4. Run `npm link lodash` which will replace the `lodash` in that project's `node_modules` with a link that points to your hacked version in `/home/me/hacked-npm/lodash`.

I do this all the time when I want to use a hacked version of a dependency, works pretty well, and is expressly designed to solve the actual problem you're having (need to use a locally-modified version of a dependency)

Comment: The `npm install` will fail if a particular dependency is not yet hosted on NPM, I am looking to skip certain deps that are not in the NPM registry yet.

Comment: Did you try `link`-ing the packages before running `npm install`, so that they're already in `node_modules` before you run the install?

If the deps are both new and not yet in a registry, then maybe remove them from the `package.json` and do your work by `link`ing them in rather than listing them as a hard dep. Once you publish the new modules you can add them back.

Comment: typically `npm install` deletes/overwrites the symlinks, which is a bug that NPM will fix with version 7. On the other hand, `yarn install` seems to have that problem covered already, so `yarn install` is currently the answer, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976626/keep-symlinks-when-running-npm-install

Comment: Basically, `npm install` will always break if you are pointing to the official NPM registry and a package is missing, I want to avoid that problem, using --skip or what not. The only other solution is to use a custom NPM registry, like verdaccio: https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio.