# Keep symlinks when running `npm install`

Tags: npm, npm-install, symlink

If we do:

```
npm link x
```

and then we run `npm install`, it will overwrite the symlinked package.

Is there a way to run `npm install` without overwriting a symlinked package? something like:

```
npm install --preserve-symlinks
```

or

```
npm install --keep-symlinks
```

here is the issue in the NPM issue tracker:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17287

Comment: Have you tried `npm install --no-delete-symlinks`

Comment: is there documentation for that option?

Comment: I'm afraid not, I once suffered from this issue, it must've sticked in my mind after never-ending searches.

Comment: supposedly NPM version 7 will solve this...for now `yarn install` should work.

Comment: I saw this repo buried in the comments of your npm issue link: https://github.com/UD-UD/npm-safe-install

Comment: Did someone found solution for this?

Comment: perhaps the best solution is run `npm install` and then re-link everything after